# App layout appears shifted to the left on iPhone 6 screen

Tags: ios, iphone, layout

I'm facing a really boring hassle that I can't figure out. I was asked to adjust some UI elements for an iOS app that runs on system versions >= 7.0. The app layout looks fine on an iPhone 4S running iOS 7.x, but appears shifted to the right on an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.x. The app makes use of storyboard but no use of Auto Layout (that would have simply resolved this issue).

The problem is that I have another slightly modified project which appears fine on the iPhone 6 though no apparent changes were made to the size of the view controllers.

Is there any chance I could find to understand why I'm getting this strange behavior? I've also tried to spot any possibile difference between the two project using FileMerge, but I haven't found nothing related to the layout. I've even checked whether there is any customized configuration for iPhone 6 by making a direct search for `IPHONE` within the project scope but I haven't found nothing related.

Please help me. Find a screenshot of the messed-up layout attached below. I'm ready to give you any other information you need.

[image]

Comment: First of all you need to integrate autolayout in you application refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutolayoutPG.pdf

Comment: @NimitParekh I know Auto Layout will immediately fix the issue, but I can't integrate it. It's not a project made by myself and my company doesn't allow me to add this feature (unfortunately!).

Comment: @downvoter(s) You should really explain me why this question isn't good. Reputation mafia always hit newbies on this site. This is a real pity.

Comment: Other wise you need to set frame of view as per the device condition check.

Answer (score 0):

You could use autolayout or, in your `viewController`'s `viewDidAppear` change every component's frame to something like: `exampleView.frame = CGRectMake(exampleView.frame.origin.x, exampleView.frame.origin.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, exampleView.frame.size.height);`

That should do the trick.

Comment: You should also look at every hardcoded number ni your code regarding to frames (TIP: search in your project "320" that is the 4s/5/5s width screen and replace it with `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width`)

Answer (score 0):

Use following Macros and to retrieve the device type.

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPOD   ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice ] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"] )
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
#define IS_IOS_7    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f)
#define IS_IOS_8    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0f)
#define IS_IOS_8_LOWER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0f)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH <= 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Following Like code may Help to Solve your problem.

```
if(IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS){
     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width,height);// Frame for 4s
}else if(IS_IPHONE_6){
     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width,height);// Frame for 6
}else{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width,height);// Frame for 6P
}
```

May this help to lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you cann't use auto layout then in other project you must me using Autoresing. Check the screenshot and you may find the difference between two projects.[image]

Comment: Yes, I already checked it too. The set values for Autoresizing are the same ones for both projects.